# Embed HTML page within another page inline, *not* with src tag

Tags: html, iframe

I have an external page that I want to embed within my page- it has it's own scripts and CSS that I don't want to conflict with mine. Normally I'd just use an `<iframe>` and be done with it, but this is a mobile optimised site, and I want to avoid extra HTTP calls wherever possible. So, I want to run the request on the server side and embed the resulting HTML within my page, so that the client never has to be make it's own request.

I can do that by doing something like:

```
<iframe id="test"></iframe>
<script>
    var doc = $("#test")[0].contentWindow.document;
    var $body = $('body',doc);
    $body.html('<h1>Test</h1>');
</script>
```

But I'd rather do this without using JavaScript at all. Is that possible? Any content I put between the `<iframe>` and `</iframe>` tags gets ignored, as it is used for compatibility reasons with browsers that do not support iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually you should be able to use the srcdoc attribute on the iframe. But, it currently is not widely [supported](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp). In the meantime your only options are javascript or just having the browser make the call with the traditional src attribute. You might look here, as I believe this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214419/alternatives-to-iframe-srcdoc) is quite relevant.

Comment: Looks like srcdoc + a shim is the answer for now at least. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a `<div>`? Optionally, set a fixed width and height and add `overflow:auto` to its CSS.

Comment: Because the page has CSS of it's own, scripts in the ```<head>``` tag, etc. It will change and be outside of my control, so I don't want to code some horrible CSS prefixing solution or something like that. I want it to be self-contained. Should have made that clearer in my question, sorry.