# Setting Request Header on DOM element initiated requests

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, request-headers

I am trying to track all requests made through an application by setting a custom request header on all outgoing requests.  I was able to accomplish this using:

```
$ajax.Setup(
    beforeSend: ...
```

However, I ran into an issue when the src attribute on a dom element (i.e. iframe, video, object, etc) was initiating the request.  When searching I had found: [How to set custom http headers when changing iframe src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694807/how-to-set-custom-http-headers-when-changing-iframe-src)  However, when I attempted this, I was unable to get it to initiate the download dialog.  That code looked like:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    context: this,
    url: URI,
    type: 'GET',
    statusCode: {
       200: function(data) {
           var id = '#download-iframe';
           var $iframe = $(id);
           if($iframe.length === 0) {
              $iframe = $('<iframe>')
                 .attr('id', 'download-iframe')
                 .appendTo('body');
           }
           $iframe.contents().find('html').html(data);
        }
     }
});
```

The response headers for that request look as follows:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="PDF.pdf"
Content-Length:86712
Content-Type:application/pdf;charset=UTF-8
```

This displayed the raw data in the iframe, but did not initiate the download.

Is there anyway to either A) (preferred) Set the request headers a different way via setting the DOM element src or B) Get the download dialog to initiate.

Comment: You write the response into the iframe using Javascript? That won't give you a download option. Let the iframe load it itself - create and insert an iframe with the src set to the URL that sends the PDF. I'm confused by your problem description though so I may be talking about the weather on Pluto...

Comment: That's what I was originally doing, when I set the src to the URL though then the DOM kicked off the request, bypassing the javascript so the request header configured in ajaxSetup never got set.

Comment: In that case it won't work. But instead of the request header, why not add a parameter to the URL? So you can still track it. In any case, writing stuff into the iframe is not a download - how would the browser know, which is the one controlling that download/save file dialog?

Comment: Yea, that's along the line of what I was thinking, which is why I was thinking option A was preferred, setting the request header on a dom initiated request another way.

Answer (score 0):

> B) Get the download dialog to initiate.

[blob URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) + [`<a download ...>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) + synthesizing a click event will probably work