# Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, rest, api, symfony

when i want to add a form with API Symfony and angular js (Frontend) i had this error can someone know why ?

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. AddUserComponent.html:16 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff
>   'server error'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
>       at DefaultIterableDiffer.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff
>   (core.es5.js:6843)
>       at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck
>   (common.es5.js:1691)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10846)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12341)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12284)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13141)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13082)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AddUserComponent.html:21)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirec

**Userservice**

```
 @Injectable()
    export class UserService {
      private uri= 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users';
      constructor(private http: Http, private authenticationService: AuthService  
     ) {}
      addUser(user: User) {
            const  headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token);
            return this.http.post(this.uri, JSON.stringify(user), {headers : headers})
            .map(res => res.json()).catch(this.handelError);
          }
```

Comment: Research "CORS", and gain some understanding.  It's very important to control cross site scripting attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is CORS issue. CORS is security implemented in browser.If you are using angular you can resolved this issue by creating  a `proxy.conf.json` file to act as a proxy server.

```
{
  "/api*": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",

  },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

And then modify the npm start command in package.json as below

> "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"

You can read more about this on **[this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)** link

Comment: i edited  "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8000"  or  localhost:4200    because i worked with symfony localhost:8000 and with angularjs localhost:4200 ? @santosh singh

Comment: target will be your api 127.0.0.1:8000/api

Comment: i run with ng server or npm start ? @santosh singh

Comment: @helen npm start

Comment: @helen : strange!

Comment: @helen : You configured the proxy as per my answer

Comment: @helen : checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898253/httpclient-angular4-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-th?rq=1

Comment: when i used npm start i have this error  "Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port." npm ERR! youtube-news@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Comment: It's looks like you are running two instances of ng server.close all the running instances

Comment: Just installed this chrome extensions and disabled the cors https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: it solved @santosh  but now i have this error did know why ""AddUserComponent.html:16 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'TypeError'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
 atDefaultIterableDiffer.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (vendor.bundle.js:54225)
 atNgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (vendor.bundle.js:16964)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.bundle.js:58228)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor)""

Comment: The reason of this error is that your iterating over the variable which is not iteratable.That's the reason ngFor is failing

Comment: i think the ngFor of errors in form add user
      <div *ngFor="let error of errors" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div>There is an error in :{{error.field}} field</div>
          <div>{{error.message}}</div>
        </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btnprimary">Save</button></form>

Comment: @helen : I think so

Answer (score 0):

This is CORS issue. CORS is security implemented in browser.

It means that you are not allowed to make HTTP request to other domain or port than yours.

In your case your application is running on `localhost:4200` but you are requesting from `localhost:8000`. Therefore this is blocked by browser.

For developing purposes you can use [angular-cli proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) which allows you to make a tunnel on 4200 port.

For production use you should either whitelist your server in CORS security headers or make your API available on the same host (like mapping /api to your backend).