# HTML as sandboxed iframe's `src` (IE11/Edge)

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-11, sandbox, microsoft-edge

With HTML5, is there any way in IE11/Edge to populate a sandboxed iframe (`<iframe sandbox></iframe>`) with HTML other than using a `src` url? I am looking for a solution like [`srcdoc`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-srcdoc) which works with all other modern browsers.

Using `src` with a [data URI](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) is not an option [according to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx) as it "cannot be used [to] populate frame or iframe elements." Surprisingly, this does works for me in Edge but only for data URIs with less than 4096 characters.

All other options that I have found, e.g. in *[Alternatives to iframe srcdoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214419/alternatives-to-iframe-srcdoc)* and *[Html code as IFRAME source rather than a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102636/html-code-as-iframe-source-rather-than-a-url)* do not work for a sandboxed iframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming usage of `<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts">` is desired or acceptable, a possible workaround would be using [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) with the following setup:

*index.html:*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <iframe onload="connectIframe()" sandbox="allow-scripts" src="iframeConnect.html" name="srcdocloader"></iframe>
  <script>

var SRCDOC_HTML = '<html><body><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"><\/script><script>console.log("loaded srcdoc and dependencies", jQuery);<\/script><h1>done!</h1></body></html>';
var loaded;

function connectIframe (event) {
  if (!loaded) {
    loaded = true;
    window.frames.srcdocloader.postMessage(SRCDOC_HTML, '*');
  } else {
    onloadSrcdoc();
  }
}

function onloadSrcdoc () {
  // ...
}

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*iframeConnect.html:*

```html
<!doctype html>
<script>
window.addEventListener("message", handler);
function handler(event) {
  if (event.source === window.parent) {
    window.removeEventListener("message", handler);
    document.write(event.data);
    document.close();
  }
}
</script>
```

Note that the iframe's `onload` event will be triggered two times. The second time will be after the `srcdoc` html and all its dependencies got loaded.